# attaching a file via iPad using Lotus Notes XPages

Tags: xpages

I am fairly sure this is not possible because of limitations of the iPad but has anyone worked with the iPad and XPages to allow a user to choose a file from the iPad to attach on an XPage?  For example, the user wants to attach a PDF file...where would he be able to get it on the iPad.  I'm not an iPad expert, but from the little that I know, I don't think this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this works in latest iOS.

Comment: Is it possible to construct URI to that file? Something like file:// on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 6 allows you to upload photos or vidoes - not any other files.